# search in collection laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a very large collection of 150 objects

```
 ...
 App\almacen {#1679
     id: 124,
     emp_id: 1,
     dst_id: 13,
     hora: 0,
     numMesa: 0,
     event_id: 1,
     created_at: "2018-01-22 11:41:03",
     updated_at: "2018-01-22 11:41:03",
   },
   App\almacen {#1680
     id: 125,
     emp_id: 1,
     dst_id: 11,
     hora: 0,
     numMesa: 0,
     event_id: 1,
     created_at: "2018-01-22 11:41:03",
     updated_at: "2018-01-22 11:41:03",
   },
   App\almacen {#1681
     id: 126,
     emp_id: 1,
     dst_id: 12,
     hora: 0,
     numMesa: 0,
     event_id: 1,
     created_at: "2018-01-22 11:41:03",
     updated_at: "2018-01-22 11:41:03",
   },
   App\almacen {#1682
     id: 127,
     emp_id: 1,
     dst_id: 20,
     hora: 0,
     numMesa: 0,
     event_id: 1,
     created_at: "2018-01-22 11:41:03",
     updated_at: "2018-01-22 11:41:03",
   },
   App\almacen {#1683
     id: 128,
     emp_id: 1,
     dst_id: 7,
     hora: 0,
     numMesa: 0,
     event_id: 1,
     created_at: "2018-01-22 11:41:03",
     updated_at: "2018-01-22 11:41:03",
   },
  ...
```

and I have to compare if the keys emp_id and dst_id are equal to a number for example 8 and return 'true' if it exists
Is there any way to do this without using 'foreach' and looking directly at the object?
already use contains (), search () but always return 'false' even if the value does exist

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `where method` on `collections` like this:

```
$collection = collect([
    ['product' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
    ['product' => 'Chair', 'price' => 100],
    ['product' => 'Bookcase', 'price' => 150],
    ['product' => 'Door', 'price' => 100],
]);

$filtered = $collection->where('price', 100);

$filtered->all();
```

Answer (score 6):

Firstwhere:

```
$exists = $items->firstWhere(['emp_id' => 8, 'dst_id' => 8]) !== null;
```

First:

```
$needle = 8;
$exists = $items->first(function($item) use($needle) { 
      return $item->emp_id === $needle && $item->dst_id === $needle ;
 }) !== null;
```

Filter:

```
$needle = 8;
$exists = $items->filter(function($item) use($needle) { 
      return $item->emp_id === $needle && $item->dst_id === $needle ;
 })->count() > 0;
```

Comment: Are you sure the first example works? I'm trying `$this->permissions->where(['user_id' => $user->id])` and it doesn't work, but this does work `$this->permissions->where('user_id', $user->id)`. There's also no reference to the array option in the Docs. If you look at the `operatorForWhere()` method in Collection.php I can't see how your example could possibly work.

Answer (score 2):

## Laravel 4.2

**`firstWhere`** (not working)

**`first:`**

```
$needle = 8;
$exists = $items->first(function($key, $item) use ($needle) { 
      return $item->emp_id === $needle && $item->dst_id === $needle ;
 }) !== null;
```

**`filter`**:

```
$needle = 8;
$exists = $items->filter(function($key, $item) use ($needle) { 
      return $item->emp_id === $needle && $item->dst_id === $needle ;
 })->count() > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
return $collection->where('price', '100')->toArray();
```